# Issues with back-end verification of google sign-in authentication token on Google app engine

Tags: python, ios, google-app-engine, google-signin, pyopenssl

I am trying to integrate Google Sign-in into my iOS app.  I am able to show the logon button in my app and get the Device authentication token after successful login.

My backend is running on Google App engine.  I am sending the device authentication token to the back-end and am trying to verify the token using the example code in  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth.

However, I am encountering the error shown at the end of the post when the back-end tries to execute client.verify_id_token  to verify the token.

The error in the logs is below.  Some searching on Stackoverflow suggests the issue will go away if I enable pyOpenSSL.  How do I do this?

One more question that may be the root cause of this failure.   What is the value I need to use for the CLIENT_ID and IOS_CLIENT_ID fields in the code in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth?

Currently, I am using the client-ID listed under  Developer Console --> APIs & Auth --> Credentials --> OAuth 2.0 client IDs --> iOS client for com.apm.smartiothome.chatime.   Is this correct?   Also, do I need to check the check-box next to this in the developer console?

***Error seen in the GAE logs***

```
Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: NotImplementedError (X509 certs are not supported by the PyCrypto library. Try using PyOpenSSL if native code is an option.)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/wsgi/service.py", line 181, in protorpc_service_app
    response = method(instance, request)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/endpoints-1.0/endpoints/api_config.py", line 1332, in invoke_remote
    return remote_method(service_instance, request)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/remote.py", line 414, in invoke_remote_method
    response = method(service_instance, request)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~chatimegae/v1.388848915040088794/apns_server.py", line 274, in registerDevice
    if(self._validateAuthToken(rcvdDeviceAuthToken,rcvdDeviceAuthType,rcvdUserID)):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~chatimegae/v1.388848915040088794/apns_server.py", line 181, in _validateAuthToken
    idinfo = client.verify_id_token(rcvdDeviceAuthToken, CLIENT_ID)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~chatimegae/v1.388848915040088794/oauth2client/util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~chatimegae/v1.388848915040088794/oauth2client/client.py", line 1012, in verify_id_token
    return crypt.verify_signed_jwt_with_certs(id_token, certs, audience)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~chatimegae/v1.388848915040088794/oauth2client/crypt.py", line 338, in verify_signed_jwt_with_certs
    verifier = Verifier.from_string(pem, True)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~chatimegae/v1.388848915040088794/oauth2client/crypt.py", line 190, in from_string
    'X509 certs are not supported by the PyCrypto library. '
NotImplementedError: X509 certs are not supported by the PyCrypto library. Try using PyOpenSSL if native code is an option.
```

Comment: Your client is sending an X509 certificate, not supported by the PyCrypto library used on App Engine. "if native code is an option" means, "if you're running on Managed Virtual Machines" rather than classic App Engine, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/managed-vms/ -- but beware, it's beta. *If* MVM is an option for you, you add libraries via mods to the docker file -- a bit long to go into not even knowing if MVM is an option at all. Else, you must code your IOS app to authenticate by other means than x509 certificates (an IOS problem, not my field).

Comment: Thanks.  What kind of certificate should the client be sending?  I can then do some searches to figure how to get my iOS app to send the required type of certificate

Comment: Also, could you please tell me what is the value to be used for CLIENT_IF and IOS_CLIENT_ID in the sample code in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth?

Comment: The client_id (same as ios_client_id if you're only developing for ios) is found in GoogleService-Info.plist , as mentioned in earlier sections of https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/ .

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful.  Could you also tell me what kind of certificate is expected so that I can figure out how to get my iOS app to send it?

Comment: actually I'm not sure which alternatives exist, much less how to specify them -- I see many listed in http://www.net.in.tum.de/fileadmin/TUM/NET/NET-2013-02-1/NET-2013-02-1_07.pdf but I'm not certain which ones app engine would like, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, a sample working app from Google cloud team that shows Google-sign in implemented on an iOS device and interacting with backend on App engine would be really helpful.

Comment: I hear you, and I'll see what I can do when I'm in the office come Monday.

Comment: Hi Alex, is there a sample code available now?